# Entity Framework: three way many-many-one relationship with Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Trying to wrap my head around this relationship and figure out how to map this with fluent api.

I have three objects; Request, Response, and Administrator

A Request can have multiple responses, from one or many administrators

A Response can be associated with ONE request, and ONE administrator.

An Administrator can be associated with MANY responses and MANY requests

Logically speaking an administrator is assigned to a request, and can create responses associated to a request that they are assigned to. I realize that schema wise an admin can create a response to a request they aren't assigned to, but this is enforced as a business rule in the application, unless there is a clean way to enforce that with schema I am not really concerned.

What I am seeing so far is the following (simplified) objects:

Request:

```
public class Request {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators {get;set;}
}
```

Response:

```
public class Response {
    public Guid Id {get;set;} 
    public virtual Request { get;set;}
    public virtual Administrator { get;set;}
}
```

Administrator:

```
public class Administrator {
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses {get;set;}
}
```

I have a feeling this is simpler than I am making it out to be. But if somebody could help me translate the fluent api mappings for this that would be wonderful! :)

**EDIT:**

Been fiddling around with this and I think I may have settled on a solution:

The response has two required mappings for request and administrator

```
public class Response: EntityTypeConfiguration<Response>
{
    public ResponseMap()
    {

        HasKey(response => response.Id);

        HasRequired(e => e.Request);
        HasRequired(e => e.Administrator);
    }
}
```

The request has a many to one with responses and a many to many with administrators with a relationship table:

```
public class RequestMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Request>
{
    public RequestMap()
    {

        HasKey(r => r.Id);

        HasMany(e => e.Responses)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Request)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasMany(or => or.Administrators)
            .WithMany(p => p.Requests)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.ToTable("RequestAdministrator");
                mc.MapLeftKey("RequestId");
                mc.MapRightKey("AdministratorId");
            });


    }
}
```

And the Administrator has a Many to one relationship with response. It also has a relationship to request but that is defined in the above mapping.

```
public class AdministratorMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Administrator>
{
    public AdministratorMap()
    {
        HasKey(e => e.Id);

        HasMany(p => p.Responses)
            .WithRequired(o => o.Administrator)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure this the right way to do this, but it seems appropriate at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code to generate a database with this database diagram:

[image: Database Diagram]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.Database.Initialize(true);
    }
}

public class Request
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
    public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }
}

public class Administrator
{
    public int AdministratorId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());
    }

    public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Response> Responses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RequestsConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AdministratorsConfig());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class RequestsConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Request>
{
    public RequestsConfig()
    {
        HasMany(r => r.Responses).WithRequired(rs => rs.Request);
        HasMany(r => r.Administrators).WithMany(a => a.Requests);
    }
}

public class AdministratorsConfig: EntityTypeConfiguration<Administrator>
{
    public AdministratorsConfig()
    {
        HasMany(a => a.Responses).WithRequired(r => r.Administrator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right this is what I have already. I was trying to figure out the Fluent API mappings for this structure.

Comment: I edited the original post with a possible solution that I may have landed on. The resultant tables are exactly the same as your diagram.

Comment: I added fluent api configuration classes into my answer

Comment: So the hasrequired on responsemap isn't necessary? Otherwise similar to what I ended up on. Seems to work in testing as well and for that reason I will mark this as the answer. :) Thanks for helping me think it through.

Comment: I initially had a response configuration class with the two hasrequired expressions. The join table disappeared. Therefore, I removed them, and it worked fine.

Comment: Interesting I'm guessing they are inherently required because they are foreign key references.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Request
{
  public int RequestId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
public int ResponseId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Request")]
public virtual int? RequestID {get;set;}
public virtual Request Request{get;set;}
[ForeignKey("Administrator ")]
public virtual int? AdministratorID {get;set;}
public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }
}

public class Administrator
{
public int AdministratorId { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is what you want

[Table("REQUEST", Schema = "YourSchema")]
public class REQUEST
{

    public REQUEST()
    {
        Responses = new HashSet<RESPONSE>();
        Administrators = new HashSet<ADMINISTRATOR>();
    }

    [Column("REQUESTID")]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RESPONSE> Responses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ADMINISTRATOR> Administrators { get; set; }
}

[Table("RESPONSE", Schema = "YourSchema")]
public class RESPONSE
{
    [Column("RESPONSEID")]
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }

    [Column("REQUESTID")]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    [Column("ADMINISTRATORID")]
    public int AdministratorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RequestId")]
    public virtual REQUEST Request { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AdministratorId")]
    public virtual ADMINISTRATOR Administrator { get; set; }
}

[Table("ADMINISTRATOR", Schema = "YourSchema")]
public class ADMINISTRATOR
{
    public ADMINISTRATOR()
    {
        Requests = new HashSet<REQUEST>();
        Responses = new HashSet<RESPONSE>();
    }
    [Column("ADMINISTRATORID")]
    public int AdministratorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<REQUEST> Requests { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RESPONSE> Responses { get; set; }
}

    public DbSet<REQUEST> Requests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RESPONSE> Responses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ADMINISTRATOR> Administrators { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you took the right approach using collections for the models of each request and response (many-many relationships). Consider applying each many to one relationship to a separate partial class for increased granularity, and separation of concern.

```
namespace ManyToManyToOneMessage
{
    public partial class Message 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Message
    {
        public Request Request {get; set;}
        public Administrator Administrator { get; set;}
    }

    public class Response
    {
        //Place response formatting here.
    }

    public class Request
    {
        //Place request formatting here.
    }

    public class Administrator  {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

This is just for one message, with a request and response.